# OrmLite "like" method with PostgreSQL, case sensevity

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, postgresql, ormlite

I use for search the following code. (with SQLite db)

```
QueryBuilder<Product, Integer> queryBuilder = getProductDao().queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.where().like(Product.PRODUCT_NAME, "%" +   productName.trim().replaceAll(" ",  "%") + "%");
PreparedQuery<Product> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();

List<Product> productList = getProductDao().query(preparedQuery);
```

All work fine, but when I start use PostgreSQL db I faced with case sensevity problem. I may using `toLowerCase()` method for input data, but how can I do it with data from DB? Should I try write custom method for searching?

Comment: `lower(productName.trim().replaceAll(" ",  "%"))`

Comment: `productName.toLowerCase().trim().replaceAll(" ",  "%")` converts only input data.

Searh - _Cat_ == in DB _cat_, but _cat_ != _Cat_ in DB

Comment: I wouldnt change ANYTHING when you insert or update into the database.  But when you QUERY, search with `toLowerCase` or `Lower()`